# How to update a field with data from another field from the same dataset with mysql?

Tags: mysql, select

table
id  |  col1  | col2  | col3

I am looking for a SQL statement for update col2 with value of col1 where condition of col3 is fullfilled.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Update sentence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

```
UPDATE theTable SET col2 = col1 WHERE col3 IS NOT NULL
```